# Getting hidden inputs in HTML (that has period in name) from a form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following HTML:

```
<body>
<form action="/test/interop/InteropServlet" method="post" id="formTester" name="formTester"> 
<input type="hidden" name="ApiName" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="test.userId" value="admin"/>
<input type="hidden" name="test.password" value="admin"/>
<input type="hidden" name="test.progId" value="CustomTester"/>
<input type="hidden" name="InteropApiData" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="TemplateData" value=""/>
```

and I would like to use Javascript to get these hidden values and set them on clicking a button. I have the following Javscript method:

```
function callAPI(myform) {
saveCookies();
myform.ApiName.value=document.getElementById("traceName").value;
myform.TemplateData.value=document.getElementById("templateXMLText").value;
myform.test.userId.value=document.getElementById("userIDText").value;
myform.test.password.value=document.getElementById("passwordText").value;
myform.action="http://"+document.getElementById("urlText").value + "/test/interop/InteropHttpServlet";
myform.submit();
}
```

and this works for the hidden inputs that do not have a period in the name (ie test.userId, test.password) as I get the error "Error: TypeError: myform.test is undefined". I am unable to rename these hidden inputs due to the fact I do not maintain the code I am calling out to and the variables must be named this.

Is there any way I can read hidden inputs that have a period in the name from a form?

Comment: You should look into `.querySelector()`. It would much easier to just use: `myform.querySelector('input[name="test.userId"]').value="whatever";` for example. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the square bracket notation for accessing elements with a period in the name. For ex:

```
myform['test.userId'].value
```

In your case, this would become:

```
...
myform['test.userId'].value=document.getElementById("userIDText").value;
myform['test.password'].value=document.getElementById("passwordText").value;
...
```

Comment: Ah, I tried everything but square brackets. Thank you for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 3):

Another option, preferable in my opinion, is to use `querySelector()` to get the specific element:

```
myform.querySelector('input[name="test.userId"]').value="whatever";
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xjG6W/

For visual purposes, in the demo I changed `test.userId` to be `type="text"`. Type in the second textbox and click the button - it will change the first textbox's value (really, it's a hidden input).

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelector

Comment: Thank you for the information - this looks neat too. I'll check it out.